# Extracting number from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to get the number from a string.

The string will always start with `n` and end with any number i.e.:

```
n1
n2
n3
n10
n100
n1000
n99999
n9999999999999
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee the string will always look like that, then

```
num = parseInt(str.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

If it always starts with a single 'n', just keep it simple:

```
var number = parseInt(value.replace('n', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Number.of = function (number) {
    if (typeof number === "number")
        return number;

    var number = number + '',
        regnum = /(-)?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*/.exec(number);

    return regnum ? (new Function('return ' + regnum[0]))() : 0;
};
```

Then just run..

```
Number.of('n12345'); // 12345
```

Mine is an incredibly careful approach to it, but what will pull a number out of anything.

```
Number.of('Hel5lo'); // 5
```

And always returns a number.

```
Number.of('There is no number here.'); // 0
```

That may or may not be helpful to you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`String.prototype.substr`**<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) (or `substring`) and an unary `+` to convert the string to a number:

```
var number = +str.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I's suggest:

```
$('dt').each(
    function(){
        var n = $(this).text().substring(1);
        $('<dd />').text(n).insertAfter($(this));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Gxusq/).

It doesn't matter, obviously, which elements you choose to use (I opted for `dt` and `dd` for the implied relationship between the input and the output). The important part is the `substring()` function; the value of `1` refers to the starting point of the resulting substring (from the second character, as JavaScript works with zero-based arrays).

Had a second number been passed, in the form `substring(1,4)` the resulting substring would have started from the second character and ended with the fifth, **unless** the string on which `substring()` is working is of a length shorter than the second argument, in which case it's treated as being equal to the length of the string.

Reference:

- [`substring()` at the Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).